# How to get total number of matching words of two text files?

Tags: java

I have two files, File1.txt and File2.txt. Both files contain texts. I want to know the total number of common words present in these files. I have got the total number of words in each file by using this code.

```
public int get_Total_Number_Of_Words(File file) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.next();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Kindly tell me how can i use this code to count the common words between two files.

Comment: And how large are your text files?

Comment: these may vary in length.

Comment: And what about punctuation etc?

Comment: do you mean distinct common words? eg if the word "hello" appears 3 times in one file and 4 in another, do we have 1 or 3 matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have some kind of comparison.  So you can use a nested loop to do it.

```
String word1, word2;
int numCommon = 0;
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2));
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        word1 = sc.next();
        while(sc2.hasNext()){
           word2 = sc2.next();
           if(word2.equals(word1))
              numCommon++;
        }
    }
    return numCommon;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map implementation.  Take the word as the key, Integer as the value that you increment whenever you found the key. Voila!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] wordList = new String[]{"test1","test2","test1","test3","test1", "test2", "test4"};
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String word : wordList) {
        if (countMap.get(word)==null) {
            countMap.put(word, 1);
        }
        else {
            countMap.put(word,  countMap.get(word)+1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(countMap);

}
```

Result is:

```
{test4=1, test2=2, test3=1, test1=3}
```

Comment: kindly elaborate via example.

Comment: You also will need to break the lines into words, for which you can use: `String line = sc.next();
             String[] words = line.split("[\\.\\s]");`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Java 8 and [a project of mine](https://github.com/fge/largetext):

```
private static final Pattern WORDS = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

final LargeTextFactory factory = LargeTextFactory.defaultFactory();

final Path file1 = Paths.get("pathtofirstfile");
final Path file2 = Paths.get("pathtosecondfile");

final List<String> commonWords;

try (
    final LargeText t1 = factory.fromPath(file1);
    final LargeText t2 = factory.fromPath(file2);
) {
    final Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();

    final Stream<String> all
        = Stream.concat(WORDS.splitAsStream(t1), WORDS.splitAsStream(t2));

    commonWords = all.filter(s -> { return !seen.add(s); })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// commonWords contains what you want
```

It could be parallelized if you chose to use a concurrent implementation of `Set`, too.

Comment: Respected sir I needed a simplified solution. However thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 list and add the words from one textfile to one list and add the words from the other text file to the other list, then compare the two and count the words that are the same.